# Units and ring extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $S\subset R$ is a ring extension can it happen that $S$ has no units, whereas $R$ has units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $S=2\mathbb{Z}\subset R=\mathbb{Z}$. For the converse, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846931/can-a-ring-without-a-unit-element-have-a-subring-with-a-unit-element); e.g., if $R$ and $S$ are rings, where $R$ has a unit, but $S$ doesn't, then $R\times S$ doesn't have a unit, but the subring $R\times\{0\}$ does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: consider $(2)\subseteq\mathbb Z$.

In general you could take *any* nontrivial ideal of an integral domain $R$, and this would be true.